# Get name of assigned variable at runtime in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

Let a class

```
case class C(val i: Int) {
  var assignee: Option[String] = None
}
```

and for a given assignment to a variable named `x`,

```
val x = C(1)
x: C = C(1)
```

how to get value `"x": String` to `x.assignee`, namely

```
assert( x.assignee == Some("x") )
```

Comment: and if this object is in array or some collection?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy good point, only on `val` assignments, else `assignee` remains `None`.

Comment: No idea what you are asking.

Comment: @tuxdna please note update with `assert`.

Answer (score 2):

Local variable names aren't available at runtime. But you can capture it with [a macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) at compile-time. See e.g. `definingValName` at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/9c442d3aed53bdc89db1ada9d5b204bf02adb339/main/settings/src/main/scala/sbt/std/KeyMacro.scala and its usages:

```
def definingValName(c: Context, invalidEnclosingTree: String => String): String = {
  import c.universe.{ Apply => ApplyTree, _ }
  val methodName = c.macroApplication.symbol.name
  def processName(n: Name): String = n.decoded.trim // trim is not strictly correct, but macros don't expose the API necessary
  def enclosingVal(trees: List[c.Tree]): String = {
    trees match {
      case vd @ ValDef(_, name, _, _) :: ts => processName(name)
      case (_: ApplyTree | _: Select | _: TypeApply) :: xs => enclosingVal(xs)
      // lazy val x: X = <methodName> has this form for some reason (only when the explicit type is present, though)
      case Block(_, _) :: DefDef(mods, name, _, _, _, _) :: xs if mods.hasFlag(Flag.LAZY) => processName(name)
      case _ =>
        c.error(c.enclosingPosition, invalidEnclosingTree(methodName.decoded))
        "<error>"
    }
  }
  enclosingVal(enclosingTrees(c).toList)
}

def enclosingTrees(c: Context): Seq[c.Tree] =
  c.asInstanceOf[reflect.macros.runtime.Context].callsiteTyper.context.enclosingContextChain.map(_.tree.asInstanceOf[c.Tree])
```

Comment: Many Thanks, how to compile it (could not get onto REPL without errors), and how to run it.